# Positioning buttons around a background image

Tags: html, css

I want to position multiple link buttons around an background image. Here is the HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="background">
        <div id="abt"><a href="pages/about.html" class="button-link" id="aboutus">About Us</a></div>
        <div id="ofc"><a href="pages/office.html" class="button-link" id="office">Office</a></div>
        <div id="staf"><a href="pages/staff.html" class="button-link" id="staff">Staff</a></div>
        <div id="msg"><a href="pages/message.php" class="button-link" id="message">Message</a></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I want to position them around the background so that they stay fixed.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/kimonante/2cvz4/1/

```
body {
    background:url(http://www.factoryoutletstores.info/img/usa-map.gif) no-repeat;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    /*fix the shit*/
    background-position:center;
}
.button-link {
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: solid 1px #20538D;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    padding: 10px 25px;
    background: #0d0f12;
    color: #FFF;
    font-family:arial;
    font-weight:600;
    display:block;
}
.button-link:hover, .button-link:focus {
    background: #356094;
    border: solid 1px #2A4E77;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.button-link:active {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    background: #2E5481;
    border: solid 1px #203E5F;
}
a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:white;
    width:100px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    padding-left:18px;
}
#abt {
    margin-left:540px;
    margin-top:200px;
}
#ofc {
    margin-left:160px;
    margin-top:105px;
}
#msg {
    margin-left:930px;
    margin-top:-240px;
}
#staf {
    margin-left:360px;
    margin-top:260px;
}
```

Comment: Do you have an actual question here? What isn't working for you?

Comment: this makes almost no sense, but I think you're looking for position:fixed; not absolute.

Answer (score 0):

As your buttons are positioned by pixels, you need to set your `div#background` to a fixed size and set the background to the `div#background` instead of the body.

Also remove the background attachement. This version works: http://jsfiddle.net/BTVZz/

Comment: I added a working fiddle. There was just some positioning necessary.